# Gridview: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 3 GridView controls in 3 different pages.They worked fine before.
Suddenly I got this error message:

> Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableeventvalidation="true" />`

So I tried to put `<@pages enableeventvalidation="false" />` in the page. It still did not work.
I deleted this command from page. Then another message shows up " Index was out of range" when click the buttons in the gridview for all the girdview controls.

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(myGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value)
```

It looks like the gridview could not find the datakey (`e.rowIndex`'s value is OK), Datakeynames has been set.

```
protected void gvItemCategory_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) {

    int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemCategory.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    CollectionCategory category = new CollectionCategory();
    category.CategoryId = categoryId; 
    category.Delete();
    ItemCateogryShowData();
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItemCategory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
OnRowCancelingEdit="gvItemCategory_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowDeleting="gvItemCategory_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvItemCategory_RowEditing"
    DataKeyNames="CategoryId" OnRowUpdating="gvItemCategory_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CateogoryName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemCategoryName" runat="server"    Text='<%#Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbItemCateogryName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you manipulating anything via javascript(e.g. adding items to a dropdown)? Are you databinding the grid on postbacks? Then the index goes to -1 which would be out of range.

Comment: what happens when u try enableeventValidation="false"..

Comment: after put  enableeventValidation="false" in the page, "Invalid postback or callback argument" error message disppeared, I could see the page content. But gridview buttons have problem

Comment: No ,i did not use javascript. But I did use dropdownlist auto postbacks. But not on all the pages. The problem happened on all the pages which has gridview

Answer (score 0):

Try  binding your Gridview on pageload `!ispostback` method..

```
If(!isPostback)
{
 //your code here
}
```

Try this

```
int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemCategory.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.Tostring());
```

**NOTE**:Also use `EnableeventValidation="false"`

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. string id = myGridView.DataKeys[row.rowIndex].value.ToString()

Comment: Sorry , I typed [row.RowIndex] by mistake. It is [e.rowindex] in my code. It did not work.

Comment: Problem Solved:
      
use:  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)

Link: http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/repeaters-and-lost-data-after-postback-viewstate/

Thanks for everyone !